# Try to understand the proof of a theorem on $\pi$ and $d$ system

Tags: measure-theory

Theorem says: Let $\mu_1m\mu_2$ be measure on $(E,\mathcal{E})$ with $\mu_1(E),\mu_2(E)<\infty$. Suppose $\mu_1=\mu_2$ on $\mathcal{A}$ where $\mathcal{A}$ is $\pi$ and $\sigma(\mathcal{A}) = \mathcal{E}$. Then $\mu_1=\mu_2$ on $\mathcal{E}$

Proof: 
$$D = \{A \in \mathcal{E}: \mu_1(A) = \mu_2(A)  \} $$
By hypothesis, $E \in D$.

I do not understand this part. How do we know that $E \in D$ without even knowing that $E\in\mathcal{A}$, and hence $\mu_1(E)$ may differ from $\mu_2(E)$?

Comment: What does $\pi$ mean?

Comment: Presumably "$\mathcal A$ is a $\pi$-system".

Comment: yes, sorry I meant $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\pi$ system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hypothesis "$\mu_1(E)=\mu_2(E)$" needs to be added. **Example:** $E=[0,1]$ with Borel sets $\mathcal E$, $\mu_1$ is Lebesgue measure on $(E,\mathcal E)$, $\mu_2=\mu_1+\delta_0$, $\mathcal A=\{(a,b]: 0<a<b\le 1\}$. (Here $\delta_0$ denotes a unit point mass at $0$.)

Comment: This is what I thought, too..